# How to do ebMS3 AS4 messaging from C# client application

Tags: c#, .net, wsdl, ebxml

I am looking out for developing a C# application which posts message to a  ebMS3 platform using AS4.  I am new to this area. Could anyone please help? Is there any third party libraries to do this easily? If not, how we post messages using AS4 from a c# solution.

Comment: were you ever able to find or build a solution for this?

Answer (score 9):

I have just implemented our own AS4 solution, and it is hard task to accomplish. Especially because .NET does not support SOAP with attachments out of the box. And there is a lot background knowledge you need to know about - all the different specifications AS4 is based on. I have not been able to find an AS4 API written in .NET without it being a standalone solution as well...

First thing is to understand AS4, and a good place to start is this blog: 
https://www.codit.eu/blog/2016/02/03/as4-for-dummies-part-ii-messaging-overview/

And then you will have to understand most of the EBMS3 specification:
http://docs.oasis-open.org/ebxml-msg/ebms/v3.0/core/ebms_core-3.0-spec.html

That being said - it is not impossible.

I have been looking at the AS4.NET framework as Sander talks about, and it is well-written and a very good starting point for exchanging AS4 messages. I have used it as a test-endpoint.

So unless you need to incorporate AS4 directly into an existing product (which we needed to), I can only recommend using AS4.NET.

AS4.NET is also open source (and e-SENS profile conformant), so you can have a look at their code-base and let you inspire by the hard parts in AS4.

For the MIME parts I can recommend Mimekit: https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit
And for some of the encryption/signing stuff Bouncycastle is great: http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

Comment: Thanks for the positive feedback on AS4.NET :)

Comment: This is about THE ONLY AS4 on .NET article on internet I managed to find :-) 

Is it possible to send message from C# to AS4.NET? 
By looking at AS4.NET documentation, I found only file based communication which I can not use and would need to use some sort of web api or whatever instead. 
This AS4 stuff is so overwhelming that I got a feeling our government is trying to kill all small IT companies in DMS sector.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure whether it can be used as a library, but for a project within the European Commission an open source .NET based AS4 implementation was developed. You can find it [here](https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/code/projects/EDELIVERY/repos/eessi-as4.net/browse) in the EC's code repository. I don't know if there is any support on this, so if that is important you should probably consider another implementation. A list of solutions tested by the EC for conformance with their own profile of AS4 is available [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjI7aXdj-XaAhUQZ1AKHZyxCgMQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fec.europa.eu%2Fcefdigital%2Fwiki%2Fdisplay%2FCEFDIGITAL%2Fe-SENS%2BAS4%2Bconformant%2Bsolutions&usg=AOvVaw293oTIzwMP_-guwmA4QLMt) (or if that link doesn't work by searching for "as4 conformance tested implementations")

Note that most are standalone applications which you connect to for executing the AS4 message exchange. Most offer different integration options, so you should be able to integrate it into your solution.

Comment: Hmmm. Pretty much an ad for your own product, and an answer based on two external links that will probably rot out in no time. This is why "tell me about an API I can use" questions are not great for SO.

Comment: @mikkelbm check out the edit to this answer and all will be made clear

Comment: @jdv - ahh okay... I missed that one :-)